# Spring MVC project validation dosn't react to @Valid

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I have following project in spring mvc project but somehow validation dosn't work in my application here is lib part  of pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is dto class where I used javax.validation lib

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;


@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AccountControlRequestDto {
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String debitAcount;
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String creditAccount;
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String username;
}
```

Here is controller class in spring mvc project

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

    @Operation(summary = "add leads transaction controller")
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<?> addControllerToAccount(@Valid @RequestBody List<AccountControlRequestDto> requestDto){
        service.saveAccountControl(requestDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Created");
    }
```

Bu it still didn't react to that @Valid annotation

I wonder why this react this thanks for understanding and responses.

Comment: Remove `validation-api`, fix imports to be `jakarta.validation` (which is included by `spring-boot-starter-validation` already). Restart your application. I'm assuming you are using Spring Boot 3. Also `@Valid` on a `List` might not work as it would expect a single element.

Comment: yes your are right

Comment: Do you have `@Validated` on the Controller-class?

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are using Spring boot version 3.
Difference between Spring Boot 2 and Spring Boot 3 is javax packages were replaced with jakarta packages.

All those dependencies are located in this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Imports should be:

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
```

not

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.Valid;
```

With that in mind you do not need

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

in your pom.xml

If you are using JPA or Hibernate this also applies, imports should be `jakarta` not `javax`.

Do not forget to pull depenedencies after you change your pom.xml in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

> Bu it still didn't react to that @Valid annotation

Now, according to your code there is nothing what would initiate a reaction. The validation may run, but you neither catch the result nor do anything with that result.

To get the information whether the validation succeeded or not you have to place `BindingResult` directly after the dto to be validated and later on you can use this object for further process:

```java
@PostMapping()
public ResponseEntity<?> addControllerToAccount(
        @Valid @RequestBody AccountControlRequestDto requestDto,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
                { /* do whatever you wanna do */ };

            service.saveAccountControl(requestDto);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Created");
}
```